# route53で取得した独自ドメインから、アクセスできない。

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

webサイトをサーバーにあげるために、AWSの公式ドキュメント(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) )に沿ってS3でバッケット(独自ドメインの名前と同じ)を作り、S3のStatic website hostingのエンドポイントからはサイトにアクセスできます。しかしroute53 でrecord set(Type:A-IPv4, Alias:yes, AliasTarget:S3 Endpoint URL,　Evaluate target health: NO)をしましたが、独自ドメインでアクセスすることができません。
ドメインの先頭に『[http://独自ドメイン](http://%E7%8B%AC%E8%87%AA%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)』を付けるとGandi.netにもページが飛んでしまいます。

ググっても解決できないので、どなたか解決方法知っている方がいたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

まずは、問題の切り分けとして、以下のコマンドを実行して、
意図した結果が出力されるか確認すると良いと思います。

`nslookup 独自ドメイン`

問題がなければ、以下のように`独自ドメイン`と`S3のStatic website hostingのエンドポイント`の対応が表示されると思います。(CNAME でなく、 canonical nameと表示される場合もあり)

```
独自ドメイン CNAME S3のエンドポイント
```

問題があれば修正が必要になります。

DNSへの反映は一定時間かかるので、
数時間は`nslookup`でチェックし反映されているかを確認する必要があります。

Comment: ご解答ありがとうございます。『nslookup 独自ドメイン』した結果、上記のような反応が表示されませんでした。すでに3週間ほどこのエラーで悩んでいます。

Comment: 独自ドメインはAWSから取得しましたか?それとも、別の会社から取得されましたか? もし別の会社から取得されたのなら、その会社のネームサーバーに`Route53`の4つのDNSを登録する必要があります。(参考: [お名前.com で取ったドメインを Amazon Route53で管理し、サブドメインをはてなブログに割り当てるまで](https://tech.tanaka733.net/entry/2013/09/15/お名前.com_で取ったドメインを_Amazon_Route53で管理し、サブド))

Comment: 独自ドメインはroute53で取得しました。

Comment: https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/register-domains-route53/#toc--hosted-zone によると、ドメインを登録する前に、先に`Hosted Zone`を作成すると、`Your Domains`内の購入したドメインの4つの`Name Server`と`Hosted Zone`の4つの`Name Server`が異ることがあるようです。その場合は、`Your Domains`内の該当ドメインの4つの`Name Server`を修正し、`Hosted Zone`を設定する必要があるようです。`Your Domains`と`Hosted Zone`の4つの`Name Server`の値に差異がないか確認すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　そこは修正したことがないので試してみます！！

Comment: 無事に独自ドメインからアクセスできるようになりました！！ありがとうございました。！